# pass value of selcted item in a dropdownlist to controller in spring mvc hibernate annottations

Tags: mysql, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, hibernate-annotations

Hi in my spring hibernate annotations  application i am using jsp as view. In jsp i am loading values to a dropdownlist from my mysql database.But i can't transfer the selected values from jsp page to controller. I have two table **employee** table and **team** table in mysql.I want to display all employee in the selected team. For eg if i am selecting ***team1*** from dropdown i want to display all employees in team1.I am getting null pointerexecption error on clicking submit button.

my jsp page code snippet for loading mysql database value to dropdownlist

```
 <form:form method="POST" action="Search.html">
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
                        <form:label path="teams.teamId" id="teams">Team Name</form:label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form:select path="teams.teamId" cssStyle="width: 150px;">    
                            <option value="-1">Select a type</option>
                            <c:forEach items="${teamKey}" var="teams">
                            <option value="${teams.teamId}" >${teams.teamName}</option>

                            </c:forEach>

                             <tr>
                       <td colspan="2"><input type="submit"  value="submit">  </td>

</tr>

                        </form:select>
    </tr>
   </table>
</form:form>
```

Hibernate select query in resourcedaoimpl

```
 @Override
public void serchResources(int teamid) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("teamid is given----------  :"+teamid);
    sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM Resource WHERE teamId=" +teamid);


    System.out.println("After query  teamid is given--*************  :"+teamid);

}
```

contrtoller class

```
@RequestMapping(value="/Search",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView fromSearch(@ModelAttribute("command") Resource resource,BindingResult result){
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/searchResult.html");
    }



@RequestMapping(value="/searchResult",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView searchResult(@ModelAttribute("command") Resource resource,BindingResult result){
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    //to  print employee table
    model.put("resourcekey",resourceServices.listResources());
    //lists teams
    model.put("teamKey", addteamServices.listTeams());

    return new  ModelAndView("Search",model);
}
```

Thanks for any advice..

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `modelAttribute` in your form tag,

```
<form:form method="POST" action="Search.html" modelAttribute="command" >
```

So you will have the values for the model attribute , when you try to get them in the controller